# NSTreeController how to save to file

Tags: file, save, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

Hi I am using an NSTreeController to control an NSOutlineView. This application loads bookmarks from file to application. As in the SourceView example in ADC:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SourceView/index.html

My questions is how do I save the bookmark to file once user makes the changes. Should I maintain the array/tree internally in my application and save before quitting or is there any easier methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reverse the action taking place in the **populateOutline** method of **MyWindowController.m**. This method is reading the plist into one dictionary, reading a value from that dictionary, and using it to build the tree. Start with that method and follow the code to see how it is building the tree. It's using the **BaseNode** and **ChildNode** classes to build up the data model as a tree (I'm not sure why they didn't just use **NSTreeNode**). You want to reverse that procedure, ending up with an NSDictionary. You can then use **writeToFile:atomically:** to save the dictionary back to disk.

This can get as complex as you'd like to make it. For instance, the current code loads the dictionary file in a separate thread, so you could save in a separate thread, too. Or, you might want to save after every edit, again in a separate thread.